# ElasticSearch GET vs POST Search Results for Querystring

Tags: elasticsearch

Why am I getting different results for these two types of queries. 1st query return 17 results, where as the 2nd one returns 300+ records.

Also tried setting the query value for the second string to "A&B", seeing same result differences.

GET

```
GET  dev/data,legacyData/_search?q="A%26B"
```

POST

```
POST dev/data,legacyData/_search
{
   "from": 0,
   "size": 1000,
   "query": {
      "query_string": {
         "query": "A&B"
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Havez you  tried "A AND B" instead of "A&B" ?

Comment: Not sure why this is -1. I ask the same question. Why are we using a POST verb to do a search? I am new to Elasticsearch and the use of POST everywhere else I have been is to POST something, not to GET something. POST/_search makes no sense to me at all. Wish I could find an explanation somewhere in the Elasticsearch docs! Found a good answer here  https://discuss.elastic.co/t/what-is-difference-between-post-and-get-in-aggregation-request/162432

Answer (score 1):

when you are using double quotes in GET q query,

it represents that it is exact filter

```
GET  dev/data,legacyData/_search?q="A%26B"
```

its equivalent POST query is

```
POST dev/data,legacyData/_search
{
   "from": 0,
   "size": 1000,
   "query": {
      "query_string": {
         "query": "\"A&B\""
      }
   }
}
```

So try the following

```
GET  dev/data,legacyData/_search?q=A%26B

POST dev/data,legacyData/_search
{
   "from": 0,
   "size": 1000,
   "query": {
      "query_string": {
         "query": "A&B"
      }
   }
}
```

you will get same results